# How to generate links to standard library types in scaladoc?

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

I'm using sbt 0.13.7 and Scala 2.11.4.

In my `build.sbt`, I have:

```
autoAPIMappings := true
```

and in a `File.scala`:

```
/** scaladoc link to [[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration]] */
```

When running `sbt doc`, I’m getting:

```
[warn] ...:5: Could not find any member to link for "scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration".
[warn] /** scaladoc link to [[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration]] */
[warn] ^
```

Now, when I replace `autoAPIMappings := true` with:

```
apiMappings += (scalaInstance.value.libraryJar ->
                url(s"http://www.scala-lang.org/api/${scalaVersion.value}/"))
```

the compiler *still* gives the warning.

What could be a solution?

Comment: It works with `autoAPIMappings := true`, `sbt 0.13.6` and `scala 2.11.2`

Comment: @lisak mind turning your comment as an answer? It worked fine for me.

Comment: That's rather a hint :-) It will probably be a bug in SBT 0.13.7 or scala 2.11.4 or that version combination. I think that the person who answers this question should identify that bug for it to qualify as an answer :-)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, thanks for making the post more real, but, *please*, don't spoil my grammar, punctation and word play in the future. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior using sbt 0.13.7 and Scala 2.11.4.

Do you have multi-project setup? If so make sure to explicitly add settings to each project, or define the common settings in `ThisBuild` scope.

#### project/build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

#### build.sbt

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
  autoAPIMappings := true
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(app).
  settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val app = (project in file("app")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

#### src/main/scala/Hello.scala

```
/** scaladoc link to [[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration]] */
object Hello extends App {

}
```

Comment: It's a single-project setup. Clearing `~/.ivy2/` and `~/.sbt/` fixed this. Thank you. :-)